Unable to find application named 'ShellMate' というエラーが出ていて困ってます
環境はmacです。termiumを開いた瞬間に以下のメッセージが毎回表示されるので出さないようしたいのですが、ネットで調べてもShellMateの情報が少なくどうすれば良いかわかりません。
Unable to find application named 'ShellMate'


ShellMate で検索すると紹介記事が見つかりますが、心当たりはありませんか？ Macのターミナルアプリに付いてコマンドの使い方を表示してくれるAIアシスタント「ShellMate」がリリース。

心当たりあります！インストールしたのですが思ったように使えずアンインストールしました。。

ですが、もうアプリはないはずなので設定か何かが残ってしまっているのかもしれないということですね

原因がわかりました！
ShellMateというアプリケーションをインストールして使っていましたが、autoでログインして使うような設定を残して削除してしまった影響のようでした。
設定をオフにして削除したらtermium起動時に表示されなくなりました！
